# php-gpg (github repository) encrypts PGP message with 1 subkey fine, but not 2 subkeys?

Tags: php, gnupg

I was trying to get the php-gpg library to work from;
https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg

And if I try and encrypt a message using a PGP public key that has 2 subkeys, I get the two following errors.

> gpg: public key decryption failed: wrong secret key used gpg:
>   decryption failed: secret key not available

But if I delete one of my subkeys and only use one, it works. How can I get it to work with 2 subkeys?

Also, once I decrypt a message that is encrypted with a PGP public key that has 1 subkey, I get the following error.

> gpg warning message was not integrity protected

Does anybody have experience with this library and how to fix these problems? 
The author is not somebody who likes to answer questions about his own work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the `Public_Key.php` that causes some fingerprints to be computed the wrong way.

You are probably using the version of the file that belongs to [a revision from 2014-02-04](https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg/blob/fad8b26f62c5ca946b3892ed4d44023995150147/libs/GPG/Public_Key.php). That version contains a change that intends to fix a problem with computing public key fingerprint for the keys that use the new packet format (defined in [RFC4880 section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-4.2)).

I debugged this code for a similar problem, and found out that the current fix introduces assumption that a public key only contains one key (and no subkeys). With the public key file containing some subkeys, the last subkey will be returned, but with a fingerprint of a master key. This leads to an incorrect public key and in result all data encrypted with this corrupted key can't be decrypted.

I believe that the quick fix for this version is:

**1)** Uncomment line #143 - to make the library compute correct fingerprint for all subkeys

**2)** Change the line #90 from:

```
if ($len > 191 && $len < 224) $len = (($len - 192) << 8) + ord($sa[$i++]);
```

to:

```
if ($len > 191 && $len < 224) $len = (($len - 192) << 8) + ord($sa[$i++]) + 192;
```

according with the [RFC4880 section 4.2.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-4.2.2.2).

**3)** (Optionally) Comment out the lines #134-140 as they will no longer have any effect on the results.

I didn't test yet how does this affect keys with ElGamal, but when I do I'll try to commit the change to the official repository.

P.S. I don't know about the original author, but the maintainer seems to answer the questions on [the php-pgp issues page](https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg/issues).